# Driver probe order in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I have two drivers Dr1 and Dr2. My requirement is Dr1 probe has to call first then Dr2 probe can be called.
As both Dr1 and Dr2 sources are in the same folder, I have added Dr1 entry first and Dr2 entry next in the Makefile(as show below).

obj-$(CONFIG_DR1) += dr1.0

obj-$(CONFIG_DR2) += dr2.0

With the above modification, Dr1 probe is calling first and Dr2 probe is calling next.

Is this approach is correct or any other way to achieve the same requirement?
I am not sure, how driver and device binding is happen. My doubht is, if device for Dr2 comes first then Dr2 probe will be called first.

Could you please help me to understand how the device and driver binding will happen in Linux Kernel. We can control this order.

Comment: Are you using modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11645715/1183484), the order in the makefile is the correct approach to this.

See also [this other SO answer for a detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989671/1183484) of the mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will go through the provided links for more understanding.

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605653/linux-module-init-vs-core-initcall-vs-early-initcall/18606561#18606561). #self-promotion